# Landing at one U.S. port, but ultimate destination is another city - problem?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, study

I am travelling to the University of Dayton (first time), but for this time I am not landing in Dayton. I am landing in Charlotte, and will be going to Dayton a week later. Will there be any problem at the port of entry?

Comment: Will you be attending the university on a student visa or are you a visitor?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I believe you might have the same problem as previously covered in *[Is it recommended I enter the US only in the city where my university is situated?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95299)*, to which the quick answer is no: you should not have any problems with immigration officials for visiting cities besides those you might have submitted in your visa application.